# How is Java's ThreadLocal implemented under the hood?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local, thread-static

How is ThreadLocal implemented? Is it implemented in Java (using some concurrent map from ThreadID to object), or does it use some JVM hook to do it more efficiently?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

All of the answers here are correct, but a little disappointing as they somewhat gloss over how clever `ThreadLocal`'s implementation is.  I was just looking at the [source code for `ThreadLocal`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java) and was pleasantly impressed by how it's implemented.

**The Naive Implementation**

If I asked you to implement a `ThreadLocal<T>` class given the API described in the javadoc, what would you do?  An initial implementation would likely be a `ConcurrentHashMap<Thread,T>` using `Thread.currentThread()` as its key.  This will would work reasonably well but does have some disadvantages.

- Thread contention - `ConcurrentHashMap` is a pretty smart class, but it ultimately still has to deal with preventing multiple threads from mucking with it in any way, and if different threads hit it regularly, there will be slowdowns.
- Permanently keeps a pointer to both the Thread and the object, even after the Thread has finished and could be GC'ed.

**The GC-friendly Implementation**

Ok try again, lets deal with the garbage collection issue by using [weak references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference).  Dealing with WeakReferences can be confusing, but it should be sufficient to use a map built like so:

```
 Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<Thread, T>())
```

Or if we're using [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) (and we should be!):

```
new MapMaker().weakKeys().makeMap()
```

This means once no one else is holding onto the Thread (implying it's finished) the key/value can be garbage collected, which is an improvement, but still doesn't address the thread contention issue, meaning so far our `ThreadLocal` isn't all that amazing of a class.  Furthermore, if someone decided to hold onto `Thread` objects after they'd finished, they'd never be GC'ed, and therefore neither would our objects, even though they're technically unreachable now.

**The Clever Implementation**

We've been thinking about `ThreadLocal` as a mapping of threads to values, but maybe that's not actually the right way to think about it.  Instead of thinking of it as a mapping from Threads to values in each ThreadLocal object, what if we thought about it as a mapping of ThreadLocal objects to values *in each Thread*?  If each thread stores the mapping, and ThreadLocal merely provides a nice interface into that mapping, we can avoid all of the issues of the previous implementations.

An implementation would look something like this:

```
// called for each thread, and updated by the ThreadLocal instance
new WeakHashMap<ThreadLocal,T>()
```

There's no need to worry about concurrency here, because only one thread will ever be accessing this map.

The Java devs have a major advantage over us here - they can directly develop the Thread class and add fields and operations to it, and that's exactly what they've done.

In [`java.lang.Thread`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java) there's the following lines:

> ```
> /* ThreadLocal values pertaining to this thread. This map is maintained
>  * by the ThreadLocal class. */
> ThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMap threadLocals = null;
> ```

Which as the comment suggests is indeed a package-private mapping of all values being tracked by `ThreadLocal` objects for this `Thread`.  The implementation of `ThreadLocalMap` is not a `WeakHashMap`, but it follows the same basic contract, including holding its keys by weak reference.

`ThreadLocal.get()` is then implemented like so:

> ```
> public T get() {
>     Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
>     ThreadLocalMap map = getMap(t);
>     if (map != null) {
>         ThreadLocalMap.Entry e = map.getEntry(this);
>         if (e != null) {
>             @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
>             T result = (T)e.value;
>             return result;
>         }
>     }
>     return setInitialValue();
> }
> ```

And `ThreadLocal.setInitialValue()` like so:

> ```
> private T setInitialValue() {
>     T value = initialValue();
>     Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
>     ThreadLocalMap map = getMap(t);
>     if (map != null)
>         map.set(this, value);
>     else
>         createMap(t, value);
>     return value;
> }
> ```

Essentially, use a map *in this Thread* to hold all our `ThreadLocal` objects.  This way, we never need to worry about the values in other Threads (`ThreadLocal` literally can only access the values in the current Thread) and therefore have no concurrency issues.  Furthermore, once the `Thread` is done, its map will automatically be GC'ed and all the local objects will be cleaned up.  Even if the `Thread` is held onto, the `ThreadLocal` objects are held by weak reference, and can be cleaned up as soon as the `ThreadLocal` object goes out of scope.

---

Needless to say, I was rather impressed by this implementation, it quite elegantly gets around a lot of concurrency issues (admittedly by taking advantage of being part of core Java, but that's forgivable them since it's such a clever class) and allows for fast and thread-safe access to objects that only need to be accessed by one thread at a time.

**tl;dr** `ThreadLocal`'s implementation is pretty cool, and much faster/smarter than you might think at first glance.

If you liked this answer you might also appreciate my (less detailed) [discussion of `ThreadLocalRandom`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41760223/113632).

<sub>`Thread`/`ThreadLocal` code snippets taken from [Oracle/OpenJDK's implementation of Java 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/jdk8-b132).</sub>

Comment: Your answers looks awesome but it's too long for me right now. +1 and accepted, and I'm adding it to my getpocket.com account to read it later. Thanks!

Comment: I need a ThreadLocal-like thing that also let's me access the full list of values, much like map.values().  So, my naive implementation is a WeakHashMap<String, Object> where the key is Thread.currentThread().getName().  This avoids the reference to the Thread itself.  If the thread goes away, then nothing is holding the Thread's name anymore (an assumption, I admit) and my value will go away.

Comment: I actually [answered a question to that effect quite recently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15654081/113632).  A `WeakHashMap<String,T>` introduces several problems, it's not threadsafe, and it "is intended primarily for use with key objects whose equals methods test for object identity using the == operator" - so actually using the `Thread` object as a key would do better.  I would suggest using the Guava weakKeys map I describe above for your use case.

Comment: I ended up using regular HashMap and manually synchronized access to it.  The Map is supposed to hold a bunch of connections to APNS.  If the context is destroyed, I want an opportunity to gracefully close those connections.  In the meantime, I want to reuse the connection if I've already made it.  Despite your warning to never use the other solution, I think my situation warrants it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well the weak keys aren't necessary, but consider using a ConcurrentHashMap over a synchronized HashMap - the former is designed for multi-threaded access and will work much better in the case where each thread is generally accessing a different key.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `ThreadLocal` have any fields, or is it simply used as an identity token?

Comment: Just one, `private final int threadLocalHashCode`, used to lookup the `ThreadLocal` in the `Thread` map in a collision-avoiding way.  Other than this, `ThreadLocal` itself has no state.  Note you can see the source to `ThreadLocal.java` in your own install of Java, look for a `src.zip` file.

Comment: @dimo414: Thanks for an informative answer! Did you understand how the "stale" entries (the term used in the source to refer to entries where the `ThreadLocal` object is GC:ed) are used? Specifically, exactly when are they removed? Could you write a few words about that?

Comment: @Lii - great question.  I'll try to revisit my answer in more detail at some point, but in essence it looks to be some additional garbage collection to clean up the case where `Thread`s are long-lived but `ThreadLocal`s are regularly falling out of scope.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Any idea why they went with a custom implementation instead of `WeakHashMap`? Also, wouldn't it make sense to have a cleanup process for threads that stay in scope but are no longer runnable?

Comment: @shmosel thanks, glad it was informative! I believe it's because `ThreadLocal`'s requirements are subtly different from a `WeakHashMap`. For instance it uses a [custom hashing function](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/43cb25339b55/src/share/classes/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java#l76) "* that eliminates collisions in the common case where consecutively constructed ThreadLocals are used by the same threads*", and provides [different cleanup semantics](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/43cb25339b55/src/share/classes/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java#l626).

Comment: I'm conjecturing, but my guess is that `ThreadLocal` tries to do *less* cleanup because time spent cleaning up stale values is wasteful, and for `ThreadLocal`'s use case it's safe to do less of it than `WeakHashMap` requires.

Comment: @dimo414 `t.threadLocal = null;` seems like a pretty cheap cleanup to me.

Comment: @shmosel this class is *highly* tuned, so I would start from the assumption that such considerations have been made. A quick glance shows that when a thread terminates normally [`Thread.exit()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/43cb25339b55/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#l749) is called and you'll see `threadLocals = null;` right there. A comment references [this bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4006245) which you might also enjoy reading.

Comment: Isn't that ThreadLocal<T> concept similar to what we have in Spring as Scope and Lookup ... i.e.  T class is annotated with something like @Scope("Thread") and the method providing thread local object is annotated with Lookup ?

Comment: I haven't used Spring, but most languages have a [thread-local mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) of some sort.

Answer (score 34):

You mean `java.lang.ThreadLocal`. It's quite simple, really, it's just a Map of name-value pairs stored inside each `Thread` object (see the `Thread.threadLocals` field). The API hides that implementation detail, but that's more or less all there is to it.

Comment: I can't see why any should be needed, given that by definition the data is only visible to a single thread.

Comment: Correct, there's no synchronisation or locking around or within the ThreadLocalMap, as it's only accessed in-thread.

Answer (score 9):

ThreadLocal variables in Java works by accessing a HashMap held by the Thread.currentThread() instance.

Comment: That's not correct (or at least it isn't any longer).   Thread.currentThread() is a native call in the Thread.class.

Also Thread has a "ThreadLocalMap" which is a single-bucket (array) of hash codes.  This object doesn't support the Map interface.

Comment: That's basically what I said. currentThread() returns a Thread instance, which holds a map of ThreadLocals to values.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you're going to implement `ThreadLocal`, how do you make it thread-specific? Of course the simplest method is to create a non-static field in the Thread class, let's call it `threadLocals`. Because each thread is represented by a thread instance, so `threadLocals` in every thread would be different, too. And this is also what Java does:

```
/* ThreadLocal values pertaining to this thread. This map is maintained
* by the ThreadLocal class. */
ThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMap threadLocals = null;
```

What is `ThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMap` here? Because you only have a `threadLocals` for a thread, so if you simply take `threadLocals` as your `ThreadLocal`(say, define threadLocals as `Integer`), you will only have one `ThreadLocal` for a specific thread. What if you want multiple `ThreadLocal` variables for a thread? The simplest way is to make `threadLocals` a `HashMap`, the `key` of each entry is the name of the `ThreadLocal` variable, and the `value` of each entry is the value of the `ThreadLocal` variable. A little confusing? Let's say we have two threads, `t1` and `t2`. they take the same `Runnable` instance as the parameter of `Thread` constructor, and they both have two `ThreadLocal` variables named `tlA` and `tlb`. This is what it's like.

t1.tlA

```
+-----+-------+
| Key | Value |
+-----+-------+
| tlA |     0 |
| tlB |     1 |
+-----+-------+
```

t2.tlB

```
+-----+-------+
| Key | Value |
+-----+-------+
| tlA |     2 |
| tlB |     3 |
+-----+-------+
```

Notice that the values are made up by me.

Now it seems perfect. But what is `ThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMap`? Why didn't it just use `HashMap`? To solve the problem, let's see what happens when we set a value through the `set(T value)` method of the `ThreadLocal` class:

```
public void set(T value) {
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    ThreadLocalMap map = getMap(t);
    if (map != null)
        map.set(this, value);
    else
        createMap(t, value);
}
```

`getMap(t)` simply returns `t.threadLocals`. Because `t.threadLocals` was initilized to `null`, so we enter `createMap(t, value)` first:

```
void createMap(Thread t, T firstValue) {
    t.threadLocals = new ThreadLocalMap(this, firstValue);
}
```

It creates a new `ThreadLocalMap` instance using the current `ThreadLocal` instance and the value to be set. Let's see what `ThreadLocalMap` is like, it's in fact part of the `ThreadLocal` class

```
static class ThreadLocalMap {

    /**
     * The entries in this hash map extend WeakReference, using
     * its main ref field as the key (which is always a
     * ThreadLocal object).  Note that null keys (i.e. entry.get()
     * == null) mean that the key is no longer referenced, so the
     * entry can be expunged from table.  Such entries are referred to
     * as "stale entries" in the code that follows.
     */
    static class Entry extends WeakReference<ThreadLocal<?>> {
        /** The value associated with this ThreadLocal. */
        Object value;

        Entry(ThreadLocal<?> k, Object v) {
            super(k);
            value = v;
        }
    }

    ...

    /**
     * Construct a new map initially containing (firstKey, firstValue).
     * ThreadLocalMaps are constructed lazily, so we only create
     * one when we have at least one entry to put in it.
     */
    ThreadLocalMap(ThreadLocal<?> firstKey, Object firstValue) {
        table = new Entry[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
        int i = firstKey.threadLocalHashCode & (INITIAL_CAPACITY - 1);
        table[i] = new Entry(firstKey, firstValue);
        size = 1;
        setThreshold(INITIAL_CAPACITY);
    }

    ...

}
```

The core part of the `ThreadLocalMap` class is the `Entry class`, which extends `WeakReference`. It ensures that if the current thread exits, it will be garbage collected automatically. This is why it uses `ThreadLocalMap` instead of a simple `HashMap`. It passes the current `ThreadLocal` and its value as the parameter of the `Entry` class, so when we want to get the value, we could get it from `table`, which is an instance of the `Entry` class:

```
public T get() {
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    ThreadLocalMap map = getMap(t);
    if (map != null) {
        ThreadLocalMap.Entry e = map.getEntry(this);
        if (e != null) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T result = (T)e.value;
            return result;
        }
    }
    return setInitialValue();
}
```

This is what is like in the whole picture:

[image: The Whole Picture]

Answer (score -2):

Conceptually, you can think of a `ThreadLocal<T>` as holding a `Map<Thread,T>` that stores the thread-speciﬁc values, though this is not how it is actually implemented.

The thread-speciﬁc values are stored in the Thread object itself; when the thread terminates, the thread-speciﬁc values can be garbage collected.

Reference : [JCIP](https://www.amazon.in/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601)

Comment: Conceptally, yes. But as you see form other answers above the implementation is entirely different.