# Why is java.lang.ThreadLocal a map on Thread instead on the ThreadLocal?

Tags: java, thread-local, resource-leak

Naively, I expected a ThreadLocal to be some kind of WeakHashMap of Thread to the value type. So I was a little puzzled when I learned that the values of a ThreadLocal is actually [saved in a map in the Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202444/how-is-javas-threadlocal-implemented-under-the-hood). Why was it done that way? I would expect that the [resource leaks](http://www.google.com/search?q=threadlocal%2Bleak) associated with ThreadLocal would not be there if the values are saved in the ThreadLocal itself.

Clarification: I was thinking of something like

```
public class AlternativeThreadLocal<T> { 
    private final Map<Thread, T> values = 
        Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<Thread, T>());
    public void set(T value) { values.put(Thread.currentThread(), value); }
    public T get() { return values.get(Thread.currentThread());}    
}
```

As far as I can see this would prevent the weird problem that neither the ThreadLocal nor it's left over values could ever be garbage-collected until the Thread dies if the value somehow strongly references the ThreadLocal itself. 
(Probably the most devious form of this occurs when the ThreadLocal is a static variable on a class the value references. Now you have a big resource leak on redeployments in application servers since neither the objects nor their classes can be collected.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes you get enlightened by just asking a question. :-)  Now I just saw one possible answer: thread-safety. If the map with the values is in the Thread object, the insertion of a new value is trivially thread-safe. If the map is on the ThreadLocal you have the usual concurrency issues, which could slow things down. (Of course you would use a ReadWriteLock instead of synchronize, but the problem remains.)

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be misunderstanding the problem of ThreadLocal leaks. ThreadLocal leaks occur when the same thread is used repeatedly, such as in a thread pool, and the ThreadLocal state is not cleared between usages. They're not a consequence of the ThreadLocal remaining when the Thread is destroyed, because nothing references the ThreadLocal Map aside from the thread itself.

Having a weakly reference map of Thread to thread-local objects would not prevent the ThreadLocal leak problem because the thread still exists in the thread pool, so the thread-local objects are not eligible for collection when the thread is reused from the pool. You'd still need to manually clear the ThreadLocal to avoid the leak.

As you said in your answer, concurrency control is simplified with the ThreadLocal Map being a single instance per thread. It also makes it impossible for one thread to access another's thread local objects, which might not be the case if the ThreadLocal object exposed an API on the Map you suggest.

Comment: The more pernicious form of ThreadLocal memory leaks is caused by a circularity between the value and the ThreadLocal itself. This happens in subtle ways like a value that extends the class that declares the ThreadLocal as a member.

Comment: I was indeed thinking of the more problematic leak discussed by sylvarking. As to the API: this can be the same as the current one (see my clarification); the map would be hidden by a sensible API designer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I remember some years ago Sun changed the implementation of thread locals to its current form. I don't remember what version it was and what the old impl was like.

Anyway, for a variable that each thread should have a slot for, Thread is the natural container of choice. If we could, we would also add our thread local variable directly as a member of Thread class.

Answer (score 0):

Why would the `Map` be on `ThreadLocal`? That doesn't make a lot of sense. So it'd be a Map of `ThreadLocal`s to objects inside a ThreadLocal?

The simple reason it's a Map of `Thread`s to Objects is because:

1. It's an implementation detail ie that `Map` isn't exposed in any way;
2. It's always easy to figure out the current thread (with `Thread.currentThread()`).

Also the idea is that a ThreadLocal can store a different value for each Thread that uses it so it makes sense that it is based on Thread, doesn't it?

Comment: See my clarification. I think to implement it as a member of ThreadLocal is much more natural, but as I discussed in my answer this has drawbacks.