# Storing thread-specific variables in the Thread object itself

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm reading [B. Goetz Java Concurrency in practice](https://github.com/HackathonHackers/programming-ebooks/blob/master/Java/Java%20Concurrency%20in%20Practice.pdf) and now I'm at the section about how `ThreadLocal` works. I used to thinking about it as a `Map`-like structure, but he said that

> Conceptually, you can think of a ThreadLocal as holding a
>   Map that stores the thread-specific values, though ***this is***
>   ***not how it is actually implemented***. ***The thread-specific values are***
>   ***stored in the Thread object itself***; when the thread terminates, the
>   thread-specific values can be garbage collected.

what does he mean? How can I store a thread-specific value in a thread?

Comment: [How is Java's ThreadLocal implemented under the hood?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202444/how-is-javas-threadlocal-implemented-under-the-hood)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, if it was map of threads to values in the `ThreadLocal` object, the values would be never garbage collected as the `ThreadLocal` object is never destroyed.

So it's basically the opposite - `Thread` object contains the map of `ThreadLocal` keys mapped to its thread specific values. This way the full map is garbage collected once thread finishes.

There are few other optimizations, it actually uses direct `ThreadLocalMap` implementation instead of implementing `Map` interface, uses incremental hash code and things like that, but basically the concept is as above.