# Why is ThreadLocalRandom implemented so bizarrely?

Tags: java, random, implementation

This question regards the implementation of `ThreadLocalRandom` in OpenJDK version 1.8.0.

`ThreadLocalRandom` provides a per-thread random number generator without the synchronization overhead imposed by Random. The most obvious implementation (IMO) would be something like this, which appears to preserve backward compatibility without much complexity:

```
public class ThreadLocalRandom extends Random {
    private static final ThreadLocal<ThreadLocalRandom> tl =
        ThreadLocal.withInitial(ThreadLocalRandom::new);
    public static ThreadLocalRandom current() {
        return tl.get();
    }
    // Random methods moved here without synchronization
    // stream methods here
}

public class Random {
    private ThreadLocalRandom delegate = new ThreadLocalRandom();
    // methods synchronize and delegate for backward compatibility
}
```

However, the actual implementation is totally different and quite bizarre:

- `ThreadLocalRandom` duplicates some of the methods in `Random` verbatim and others with minor modifications; surely much of this code could have been reused.
- `Thread` stores the seed and a probe variable used to initialize the `ThreadLocalRandom, violating encapsulation;
- `ThreadLocalRandom` uses `Unsafe` to access the variables in `Thread`, which I suppose is because the two classes are in different packages yet the state variables must be private in `Thread` - `Unsafe` is only necessary because of the encapsulation violation;
- `ThreadLocalRandom` stores its next `nextGaussian` in a static `ThreadLocal` instead of in an instance variable as `Random` does.

Overall my cursory inspection seems to reveal an ugly copy of `Random` with no advantages over the simple implementation above. But the authors of the standard library are smart so there must be *some* reason for this weird approach. Does anyone have any insight into why `ThreadLocalRandom` was implemented this way?

Comment: I haven't seen the implementation for `ThreadLocalRandom`, but I do know that [parent types should not know of/depend on their subtypes](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219543/should-a-class-know-about-its-subclasses) (in regards to your simpler alternative)

Comment: @VinceEmigh Well, both could delegate to `UnsynchronizedRandom`. Either way the major issues with the current implementation are trivially avoided.

Comment: Looks like the class was rewritten in Java 8. The JDK 1.7u79 version only has 226 LOC while the [OpenJDK 8b132 version](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.java) has 1101 LOC. The code comments right after the class declaration in the Java 8 version seem to explain some of your questions.

Comment: The internal docs of the Java 8 version mention [`SplittableRandom`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/SplittableRandom.java), from which some code is duplicated.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I see. Comments like this do not inspire confidence: "Implementations of non-core methods are mostly the same as in SplittableRandom, that were in part derived from a previous version of this class." Perhaps such copying is required to maintain backward compatibility, but if so the authors have allowed too many implementation details to leak into the documented API.

Comment: "*Comments like this do not inspire confidence*" - you seem out to get the JDK authors; why are you so concerned that they've done something wrong? If you find a bug, suggest a fix. Otherwise, rest easy in the knowledge that many, many smart people have worked on this code for almost 20 years. It's battle tested.

Comment: To your comment about leaky implementation details, that's a testament to the standards the authors hold themselves to, not a flaw. By working so hard to ensure backwards compatibility the vast majority of Java applications can upgrade with minimal issues. No small feat for a language as widely used as Java.

Comment: @dimo414 The very reason I asked this question is that I thought there must be a good reason for this bad-looking code. If I didn't think the JDK authors were good I would have assumed it's just shitty code. Regarding implementation details, they can and do change from version to version. `String.substring` changed to copy the substring in Java 7, which affects Java applications. The particular algorithm used for random number generation never should have been documented in such detail and never should have been relied on exactly. I think that's one of the many legacy mistakes in the Java API.

Comment: The `String.substring` change was (and still is) a contentious one. I'm not saying the JDK team never makes mistakes, but I'm suggesting starting from an assumption of good intent and competency, rather than using language like "bizarrely", "ugly", "no advantages", and the like. That you don't *see* the advantages doesn't mean they don't exist. I realize that's what you're trying to get at, but your framing of the question is needlessly presumptuous. I'm simply encouraging giving the JDK folks a little more benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The key problem is a lot of the code is legacy and can't (easily) be changed - [`Random`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Random.java) was designed to be "thread-safe" by synchronizing all its methods. This works, in that instances of `Random` can be used across multiple threads, but it's a severe bottleneck as no two threads can simultaneously retrieve random data. A simple solution would be to construct a `ThreadLocal<Random>` object thereby avoiding the lock contention, however this still isn't ideal. There's still *some* overhead to `synchronized` methods even when uncontested, and constructing *n* `Random` instances is wasteful when they're all essentially doing the same job.

So at a high-level `ThreadLocalRandom` exists as a performance optimization, hence it makes sense that its implementation would be "bizarre", as the JDK devs have put time into optimizing it.

There are many classes in the JDK that, at first glance, are "ugly". Remember however that the JDK authors are solving a different problem than you. The code they write will be used by thousands if not millions of developers in countless ways. They have to regularly trade-off best-practices for efficiency because the code they're writing is so mission critical.

[Effective Java: Item 55](https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA234&lpg=PA234&source=bl&ots=yZKlLfu3SY&sig=dImTAbrwnA20VQUXa2dFNvpCkc4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif0tLhxPnRAhWqsVQKHZX8DHMQ6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q&f=false) also addresses this issue - the key point being that optimization should be done as a last resort, by experts. The JDK devs *are* those experts.

To your specific questions:

> `ThreadLocalRandom` duplicates some of the methods in `Random` verbatim and others with minor modifications; surely much of this code could have been reused.

Unfortunately no, as the methods on `Random` are `synchronized`. If they were invoked `ThreadLocalRandom` would pull in `Random`'s lock-contention trouble. TLR *needs* to override every method in order to remove the `synchronized` keyword from the methods.

> `Thread` stores the seed and a probe variable used to initialize the `ThreadLocalRandom`, violating encapsulation;

First off, it's really not "violating encapsulation" since the field is still package-private. It's encapsulated from users, which is the goal. I wouldn't get too hung up on this as the decisions were made here to improve performance. Sometimes performance comes at the cost of normal good design. In practice this "violation" is undetectable. The behavior is simply encapsulated inside two classes instead of a single one.

Putting the seed inside `Thread` allows `ThreadLocalRandom` to be totally stateless (aside from the `initialized` field, which is largely irrelevant), and therefore only a single instance ever needs to exist across the whole application.

> `ThreadLocalRandom` uses `Unsafe` to access the variables in `Thread`, which I suppose is because the two classes are in different packages yet the state variables must be private in `Thread` - `Unsafe` is only necessary because of the encapsulation violation;

Many JDK classes use `Unsafe`. It's a tool, not a sin. Again, I just wouldn't get too stressed out about this fact. The class is called `Unsafe` to discourage lay-developers from misusing it. We trust/hope the JDK authors are smart enough to know when it's safe to use.

> `ThreadLocalRandom` stores its next `nextGaussian` in a static `ThreadLocal` instead of in an instance variable as `Random` does.

Since there will only ever be one instance of `ThreadLocalRandom` there's no need for this to be an instance variable. I suppose you could alternatively make the case that there's no need for it to be a `static` either, but at that point you're just debating style. At a minimum making it `static` more clearly leaves the class essentially stateless. As [mentioned](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.java#l123) in the file, this field is not really necessary, but ensures similar behavior to `Random`.

Comment: Couldn't the synchronized code be extracted to a package-private common base class, as was done with `StringBuffer`?

Comment: In practice that wouldn't be possible since `Random` and `ThreadLocalRandom` are in separate packages. Why that's the case is harder to say. Looking at the [history](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/rev/09dc601a8bb3) the class was introduced as part of [JSR 166](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/) which generally placed concurrent-friendly code in `java.util.concurrent`, so perhaps that was simply done to be consistent.